# How to calculate the overlap of two polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, vector, overlapping-features

I am trying to calculate the percentage overlap of two vector polygon layers and saving the result as a separate column. The code below is working:

```
CREATE TABLE parcels_all_shapefile_new AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, COALESCE((ST_Area(ST_INTERSECTION(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry))/ST_Area(a.wkb_geometry))*100, 0) AS aw
FROM parcels_all_shapefile_flood2 a LEFT OUTER JOIN filter_ancientwoodlands b ON ST_Overlaps(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) OR ST_Within(b.wkb_geometry, a.wkb_geometry);
```

However I am getting an extra ~50,000 rows than the original table. The `DISTINCT` function has worked for me in the past to deal with this issue, when multiple polygons are intersecting with each other.

Can anyone see what I am missing? Also does anyone know how to deal with a situation when a polygon overlaps multiple polygons and you want to add the percentages together as a single result?

**UPDATE:** The below answer worked except I had to change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE parcels_all_shapefile_aw AS
SELECT  
    a.ogc_fid, a.poly_id, a.title_no,
    SUM(COALESCE((ST_Area(ST_INTERSECTION(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry))/ST_Area(a.wkb_geometry))*100, 0)) AS aw
FROM parcels_all_shapefile_flood2 a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN filter_ancientwoodlands b ON 
        ST_Overlaps(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) OR ST_Within(b.wkb_geometry, a.wkb_geometry)
GROUP BY a.ogc_fid, a.poly_id, a.title_no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the ancient woodlands polygons do not overlap with each other, the following should do what you want ... of course you will need to fill in the columns

```sql
CREATE TABLE parcels_all_shapefile_new AS
SELECT  
    a.<columns>, -- << specify the columns you want
    SUM(COALESCE((ST_Area(ST_INTERSECTION(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry))/ST_Area(a.wkb_geometry))*100, 0)) AS aw
FROM parcels_all_shapefile_flood2 a 
    INNER JOIN filter_ancientwoodlands b ON 
        ST_Overlaps(a.wkb_geometry, b.wkb_geometry) OR ST_Within(b.wkb_geometry, a.wkb_geometry)
GROUP BY a.<columns> -- << same list as in the SELECT clause
```